# How to use the awk function in this case

Tags: bash, shell, awk

So I am trying to break up a list and put data into individual files using awk. so far I have this.. but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "45" "64" "60" "70" "74" "76"
do
        awk -v x="${i}" -F, '/x/ { print }' alluls.csv > $i.csv
done

echo "script has run"
```

However.. I get all blank files

Comment: Why are you using awk here?

Comment: @anubhava perhaps because grep isn't available :)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` variables aren't evaluated inside `/.../`; you would have to use the `match` function.

```
awk ... 'match($0, x) { print }'
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `~` didn't require `/.../` for the RHS.

Comment: @chepner - `/.../` is for delimiting RE constants, just like `"..."` is for delimiting string constants. `~` is the RE match operator just like "==" is the string/number equality operator. You can use the `~` operator on REs defined as RE constants (`$0 ~ /abc/`), as string constants (`$0 ~ "abc"`), or stored in variables (`x="abc"; $0 ~ x`) and it means subtly different things for each.

Answer (score 2):

The sensible way to do this is just a single awk command (untested):

```
awk -v valS='45 64 60 70 74 76' '
BEGIN{ split(valS,valA) }
{
    for (i=1; i in valA; i++)
        if ($0 ~ valA[i])
            print > (valA[i] ".csv")
}
END { print "script has run" }
' alluls.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for a literal "x" rather than the variable value.

Comment: @user2883071 you don't prefix awk variables with `$` any more than you would C variables. awk is not shell, it is a tool you can call from shell.